# Unicode have different width when printing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unicode

I am developing a chess engine in C#/Unity and want to print the board on a nice format. Preferably I want to print with some Unicode pieces but they end up making the board uneven, see image below:

[image]

The same seems to go for normal numbers since each row starts slightly off one another, row 1 starts more left than the others for example.

Why does my Debug.Log/prints end up like this, and how can I print them so that each character takes up the same amount of space?

EDIT:
Here is the code I use to Debug.Log the board if that helps:

```
public static void PrintBitboard(ulong bitboard)
{
    string zero = " 0 ";
    string one = " 1 ";

    string printString = "";

    // Loop through all squares and print a 1 if piece and 0 if not a piece on the square
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        // Add numbering on the left side
        printString += (8 - row) + "  ";

        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            int currentSquare = row * 8 + col;
            printString += BitOperations.GetBit(bitboard, currentSquare) != 0 ? one : zero;
        }

        // Change to new row
        printString += "\n";
    }

    // Print bottom letters
    printString += "\n" + "     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h";

    // Send message to the console
    Debug.Log(printString);
}
```

Comment: Unicode is just a semantic database. Display (glyphs) are outside Unicode: fonts are responsible. Good fonts have the property `tnum` to be activated when you put numbers tabularly. But probably you should also select the pixel position of every character

Comment: What is the character beyond the (virtual) grid? Where did you snip the picture from (I'd guess Windows Terminal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not "unicode" but [monospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

-> As GiacomoCatenazzi already said, the only thing responsible for that is the **font** you are using

As a "quick and dirty" fix / alternative you could try and simply use tabs (`\t`) instead of spaces like (in general for larger string based concatenations I would recommend to use a [`StringBuider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder))

```
public static void PrintBitboard(ulong bitboard)
{
    const string zero = "0\t";
    const string one = "1\t";

    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through all squares and print a 1 if piece and 0 if not a piece on the square
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        // Add numbering on the left side
        stringBuilder.Append((8 - row)).Append('\t');

        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            int currentSquare = row * 8 + col;
            stringBuilder.Append(BitOperations.GetBit(bitboard, currentSquare) != 0 ? one : zero);
        }

        // Change to new row
        stringBuilder.Append('\n');
    }

    // Print bottom letters
    stringBuilder.Append("\n \ta\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th");

    // Send message to the console
    Debug.Log(stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

See [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J86Ju2) which in the Unity console would look like

[image]

(in both I had to tricks a bit since I don't know what `BitOperations` implementation you are using)

Comment: Thanks, the tab solutions works for my purposes!